# CUDA kernel function

Tags: cuda

I am just wondering what is the difference between calling a CUDA kernel function with

```
<<<BLOCK_NUM, THREAD_NUM>>>
```

and

```
<<<BLOCK_NUM, THREAD_NUM, THREAD_NUM * sizeof(float)>>> ?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The additional argument in the second case specifies the amount of dynamic shared memory to be allocated to each block in the kernel.

For example, if you have a kernel defined like this:

```
__global__ void kernel(...)
{

    extern __shared__ float buffer[];

}
```

The second kernel launch would attempt to allocate `THREAD_NUM` words for the shared memory array `buffer` for each block of the kernel. See Appendix B.17 of CUDA 4.1 programming guide for more information.